# Java linked list using user input

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm only a few weeks into a Java class and I'm unsure how to proceed.  Would anyone be able to direct me to the starting points of creating a linked list using user input?
Here's what I have so far, just the request for user input. What I'm hoping to discover is how I would take the results and create my linked list?  Would I create the list within the first brackets or do I create a new bracket for this direction?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    

  public static void main (String[]args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

      System.out.println ("Enter first name of equipment, cost and gain:");
    String equipment1 = scan.nextLine ();

      System.out.println ("Enter second name of equipment, cost and gain:");
    String equipment2 = scan.nextLine ();

      System.out.println ("Enter third name of equipment, cost and gain:");
    String equipment3 = scan.nextLine ();

      System.out.println ("You have entered:");
      System.out.println (equipment1);
      System.out.println (equipment2);
      System.out.println (equipment3);
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me.  Are you supposed to leverage the existing Java LinkedList class?  Or to write your own linked list class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List is an interface, LinkedList implements List.

You can do as follows:

```
import java.util.List;

List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add(equipment1)
list.add(equipment2)
list.add(equipment3)
```

In addition, you can do also:

```
import java.util.List;

List<String> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(equipment1, equipment2, equipment3));
```

Which initialize the LinkedList and insert in the constructor.

Comment: All true, but it might be a bit early for OP to learn about interfaces. People start by learning concrete ideas, and they progress toward abstractions. On the one hand, it ought to be obvious to anybody that a `LinkedList` is a kind of list, but teaching that it `implements List` and all of the baggage that goes along with that idea can come a little bit later.

Comment: @SolomonSlow OK, agree